# Can't get rid of .idea directory in gitlab

Tags: git

it says "Nothing to commit"!

I have deleted this dir twice already. But it remains in my branch.
I had it ignored in .ignore but now I removed it. Also PHPStorm won't show it to be able to delete from the GUI.

```
$ git rm -r --cached .idea
rm '.idea/php.xml'
$ git status
On branch ft-validation-service-fix-missing-orm
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/ft-validation-service-fix-missing-orm'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    .idea/php.xml

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        src/AppBundle/Controller/TestController.php

$ git commit . -m 'Remove .idea directory'
On branch ft-validation-service-fix-missing-orm
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/ft-validation-service-fix-missing-orm'.
Untracked files:
        src/AppBundle/Controller/TestController.php

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

EDIT: Seems this was bugged, I had to re-clone the repo in another location, do the git rm and then push and pull in the other project.

Answer (score 4):

If you already added `.idea` in *.gitignore* file then remove it from git cache.

```
$ git rm -r --cached .idea
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'commit message' 

$ git status
```

---

I guess you/someone already pushed *.idea/* to remote. If so then follow -

- First, remove the .idea from .gitignore
- Close the IDE
- Go to terminal and delete the .idea folder, Add, Commit, Push (would remove .idea from remote)

  ```
  # go to project directory using terminal 
  $ rm -rf .idea
  $ ls -la        # make sure .idea is deleted successfully

  $ git add .
  $ git commit -m 'remove .idea directory'
  $ git push origin HEAD                    # remove the .idea from remote
  ```
- Open IDE (new .idea will be generated).
- Add .idea in .gitignore file
- Remove *.idea* from git cache and see `git status` should ignore .idea directory.

  ```
  # Add .idea in .gitignore file

  $ git remove -r --cached .idea    # remove .idea from git cache
  $ git status
  ```

Comment: I don't understand you, you are doing exactly the same commands I did. But if you look at the description's code, git commit says that there is nothing to commit, even if I did do `git rm -r --cached .idea`

Comment: Try the following: remove cache,  add, commit.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unnecessary `.` in your commit command, remove it and it will work fine:

```
git commit -m 'Remove .idea directory'
```

Instead of

```
git commit . -m 'Remove .idea directory'
```

The dot is interpreted by git as a [list of files to commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit-ltfilegt82308203), which will ignore whatever you have staged, and will instead only include the listed files in the commit - and for some reason the dot doesn't match the removed file.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Jetbrain](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems)

> If you decide to share IDE project files with other developers, follow these guidelines:
>   Here is what you need to share:
>   1 - All the files under .idea directory in the project root except the workspace.xml and tasks.xml files which store user specific settings
>   2 - All the .iml module files that can be located in different module directories (applies to IntelliJ IDEA)

so you have to share it if u want to code inside Jetbrain products.